# git fatal: UriFormatException encountered. actualUrl

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

I keep getting this error whether I'm syncing in Visual Studio 2017 or just doing a PUSH using Git Bash. It looks like the PUSH/PULL commands work, but I'm still seeing this error and would like for it to go away.

My Git Credential Manager for Windows is version 1.14.0
My Git version is 2.16.1.windows.4

I have uninstalled both Git and Visual Studio 2017 and re-installed and keep getting the same error. I am using VSTS for my Git repository so that is where the URL is coming from.

Here is a look at the actual error:
**Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
UriFormatException encountered.
   actualUrl**

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: What URL is your remote pointing to?

Comment: https://xyz.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/xxx%20yyy%20zzz - other members of my dev team can access this with no issues, so it seems like some leftover Git setting somewhere on my machine.

Comment: Do you have the same issue while push to other repository?

Comment: Good question and yes, I get the same error.

Comment: Seeing the same thing with SmartGit so it's probably not a Visual Studio thing, but a Git thing. I'm on 2.16.2 and Git Credential Manager 1.16 - every commit to every repo seems to throw this error, but the operations actually go through and succeed in spit of it.

Comment: Thanks, good to know, I thought maybe it was something Visual Studio did behind the scenes or maybe some config file somewhere that I haven't found. I am just living with it at this point, same as you, it still seems to work despite the error. I get the error in VS and also when using Git Bash.

Comment: Also getting this error.  Using git version 2.16.2.windows.1.  Interestingly, I'm moving to a new machine, and it's only the new machine that is having the error, not the old, even though they are using the same version.  I tried cloning a separate repo from the server onto both the new and the old.  Still, only the new computer shows the error.

It's not causing any failures, though.  Just annoying.

Comment: Wish I had a solution to offer you, I'm still just dealing with it and hoping some future upgrade will make it go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admittedly my problem ended up being an oversight on my part. We were getting 443 related errors while connecting our projects to VSTS. The fix was to add entries in our C:\Users\.gitconfig file to use a proxy server.

The GOOD entries look like this:

[http]
    proxy = `http://username:password@XXX.XXX.X.XXX:XXXX`

[https]
    proxy = `http://username:password@XXX.XXX.X.XXX:XXXX`

In my original entries I accidentally left a <> in the url string, which is why I was getting the UriFormatException error.

Bad Entry:

proxy = `http://username:<password>@XXX.XXX.X.XXX:XXXX`

Hope this helps someone else catch this silly oversight!

Answer (score 2):

If your password/username contains special characters, this might be the issue. For example, if your password/username contains "@", you can replace it by "%40" and configure proxy.

Example:

password: `git@my`

username: `admin`

`http://admin:git%40my@proxyUrl:port`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was also a C:\Users.gitconfig file problem.

The line proxy was as follwing:
**proxy = http[s]://username:password@proxyUrl:port**

Removing the square brackets did the trick:

**proxy = http://username:password@proxyUrl:port**

Answer (score 0):

For Fatel: UriFormatException issue, you need to have the clean password in .gitcongfig file. 
Please remove any special characters from the username, password, then it should work.

fyi -> proxy = http://username:password@proxyUrl:port